# Why does module os of Python not run chromehtml2pdf command?

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, google-chrome-headless

When I run the command

```
chromehtml2pdf --out=E:\Trial\test3.pdf https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stochastic_process
```

in a Windows command prompt window, it runs perfectly fine and generates the file `test3.pdf` in the folder `E:\Trial` as also output with:

```
Converting file: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stochastic_process
out = E:\Trial\test3.pdf
```

Unfortunately, when I call this command from Python with

```py
import os
cmd = "chromehtml2pdf --out=E:\Trial\test3.pdf https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stochastic_process"
os.system(cmd)
```

it returns nothing, i.e. no PDF file is generated.

The full qualified file name of `chromehtml2pdf` is:

```
C:\Users\Dung Le\AppData\Roaming\npm\chromehtml2pdf.cmd
```

I tried also:

```
import subprocess
cmd = '"C:\Users\Dung Le\AppData\Roaming\npm\chromehtml2pdf.cmd" --out="E:\Trial\test1.pdf" http://www.randomservices.org/random/foundations/Measure.html'
subprocess.run(cmd, shell = True)
```

But it returns the error:

```
File "<ipython-input-21-4339c7e1a889>", line 2
cmd = '"C:\Users\Dung Le\AppData\Roaming\npm\chromehtml2pdf.cmd" --out="E:\Trial\test1.pdf" http://www.randomservices.org/random/foundations/Measure.html'
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 3-4: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape.
```

I don't know what's wrong with:

```
cmd = '"C:\Users\Dung Le\AppData\Roaming\npm\chromehtml2pdf.cmd" --out="E:\Trial\test1.pdf" http://www.randomservices.org/random/foundations/Measure.html'
```

Could you please elaborate on this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: @LAD shouldn't the string be raw? `cmd= r""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mofu and  @HackingAddict1337's comments solve my problem. Thank you so much!

---

```
import subprocess
cmd = r'"C:\Users\Dung Le\AppData\Roaming\npm\chromehtml2pdf.cmd" --out="E:\Trial\test1.pdf" http://www.randomservices.org/random/foundations/Measure.html'
subprocess.run(cmd, shell = True)
```